# texture mapping without texture being mirrored on other side of object

Tags: node-editor, shaders, image, eevee-render-engine, texture-coordinates

I have a cylinder I want to map a texture to. 
To specify the location of the texture I use an empty.
In the material node editor I then use the object function of the texture coordinate node and select the empty in the dropdown.

So this is the result I get out of this:

[image]

[image]

As you can see on the pictures the image is not only mapped at the front of the object, but also at the backside of it (like it´s printed through the object).

Can someone help me to let it just appear at the front??

My node setup looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Maybe try and set the Texture coordinate to UV and adjust your image on the UV Editor. It should do it.